# WPF application crashes while playing video using VLC lib after sometime in Windows 10

Tags: wpf, vlc, libvlc, vlc.dotnet

I am using WPF VLC lib for playing video but app abruptly crashed without throwing any exception. I have found some error in event Viewer > Windows log > application.

```
Fault bucket 1600891151472079635, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: OMNIplay.exe
P2: 1.0.0.11
P3: 8d524c28
P4: libdcp_plugin.dll
P5: 3.0.16.0
P6: 3a493a41
P7: 40000015
P8: 000fbf77
P9: 
P10:
```

Here is the implementation

For play:

```
private VlcControl _mediaVLCPlayerElement;
private VlcMediaPlayer _vlcMediaPlayer;

var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
var vlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

var options = new string[]
                {
                    // VLC options can be given here. Please refer to the VLC command line documentation.
                    "avcodec-hw=any"
                };

_mediaVLCPlayerElement = new VlcControl();
Trace.WriteLine("Creating player begins");

_mediaVLCPlayerElement.SourceProvider.CreatePlayer(vlcLibDirectory, options);
Trace.WriteLine("Player Created");

_vlcMediaPlayer = _mediaVLCPlayerElement.SourceProvider.MediaPlayer;
_vlcMediaPlayer.Log += OnLog;
_vlcMediaPlayer.Video.FullScreen = true;
_vlcMediaPlayer.EndReached += OnMediaEnded;
_vlcMediaPlayer.EncounteredError += OnMediaFailed;
_vlcMediaPlayer.Opening += OnMediaOpening;
_vlcMediaPlayer.SetMedia(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), options);
_vlcMediaPlayer.play();
```

For disposing:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
                    try
                    {
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.EndReached -= OnMediaEnded;
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.EncounteredError -= OnMediaFailed;
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.Opening -= OnMediaOpening;
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.Log -= OnLog;
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.Stop();
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.GetMedia().Dispose();
                        _vlcMediaPlayer.Dispose();

                        if (_mediaVLCPlayerElement != null)
                        {
                            Trace.WriteLine("Player disposing...");
                            _mediaVLCPlayerElement.SourceProvider.Dispose();
                            _mediaVLCPlayerElement.Dispose();
                            _mediaVLCPlayerElement = null;
                            Trace.WriteLine("Player disposed...");
                        }

                      _vlcMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Release VLC object: " + e.Message);
                    }
                });
```

This is happening when disposing the object (when video is completed and trying to start new one).

Please let me know what wrong I am doing here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for information:-
I am using following versions:- 
VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows version  is 3.0.16
Vlc.DotNet.Core version  is 3.1.0
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops version  is 3.1.0
Vlc.DotNet.Wpf   version  is 3.1.0

Comment: Does VLC crash the same way with the same stream? it definitely sounds like a VLC crash instead of a Vlc.DotNet issue

Comment: You didn't even say what kind of media it is. When asking questions, always send full logs. Please also try with other kind of files

Comment: No, VLC does not get crashed while playing same media, I am playing .mp4 file from local. One more thing is that media has short duration like 6sec, 9 sec, playing in loop.

Comment: I handled most of the exception but when app crashes, no exception and log there, just being crashed.
I have suspect there is native reference or object of vlc lib which do not exist in c# memory not being cleared as result, process heap, stack memory are fulled and app crashed.

Comment: You should enable verbose logs, that gives you an hint. See the wiki for info on how to do that. However, we will be unable to help without a way to reproduce the issue. First try with VLC.exe and see if it crashes too